# In socket.io, can the listener act as the emitter at the same time?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, client-server

In my problem, I need to send some data from several devices to a centralized server. Then I need to view these received data in a UI from the centralized server.

I have sent data from a client to a server using socket.io methods and it worked. Now I want to send the data in the server to a UI. Can I use sockets for that? If so, is it possible and is it good to code in a way that server act as the listner and the emmiter at the same time? If this approach is not good, please provide your suggesions.

Comment: yes? they are two-way

Comment: Can you please explain those ways briefly?

Comment: server-to-client and client-to-server. Socket.io isn't sockets, but I'm pretty sure socket.io's can send and receive.